# Error in Compiling Nvidia Blast : WindowsError: [Error 5]

Tags: python, nvidia

I'm working with [Nvidia Blast](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/Blast) and trying to compile the it. I follow the instructions to run 'generate_projects_vc15win64.bat'. Error occurs when installing 'CapnProto', one of its dependency (seems in checking installation).

[image]

It seems an access error, but it still occurs when I run 'generate_projects_vc15win64.bat' as administrator.

Comment: Does the file exist? ave you tried to manually install CapnProto?

Comment: I'm sure the file exists. I install manually but  'generate_projects_vc15win64.bat' will remove it and re-install again.

Comment: Well, it is confusing that it was installed successfully after I tried lots of times.